# Detect actual form change?

Tags: javascript, html, prototypejs

Is there a ready-made way (maybe in one of the frameworks) to detect whether a form has **changed** compared to its original values?

The onchange event won't do, because it fires regardless of actual change (I could for example tick a checkbox on, and off again, with two onchange events).

The last resort would be to store each element's original value in a hidden field, and go through each one. If there is a faster method, I'd be happy to hear about it!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/598951/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-detect-if-at-least-one-field-has-been-changed-on-an-ht/598977#598977

Comment: Cheers, serializing was the new idea I was looking for.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm not aware of any DOM event that detects changes made to children/descendant elements' value attributes, but it should be enough to compare the [serialized](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/form/serialize) values before/after, `$('form').serialize()`. I apologize if you already knew about this method specifically, I'm assuming you're manually going through form elements and appending values to a string.

Comment: No, I didn't know/think about serializing. It's a great idea, thanks!

Comment: It's a great solution. Too bad it doesn't work for complex forms with div's and fieldset-definitions..

Answer (score 0):

I'm hunting for the same answer - here's the best potential solution I've come across (but haven't tried it yet):  http://www.codingforums.com/showthread.php?t=29410&highlight=form+dirty